# Error when calling ASP.NET pagemethod from javascript function that outputs more than 100 records

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pagemethods

I have a javascript function that calls an asp.net pagemethod. it was working fine until today when I noticed it would occasionally stop working. After extensive testing, I realized that when the pagemethod returns 100 or more rows, the javascript function errors out. I'm currently using the Stringbuilder to append records and then I use javascript function to update a control on the page (in this case its just an asp:label). my goal is to be able to click the header buttons to sort by column without have reload page. Now if I call the pagemethod from within code-behind (see example 1), there is no issue so it apears to be related to the javascript function, but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Does javascript impose some sort of limit on strings?  Here is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

example 1:

```
activeLbl.Text = getTest();
//This works as expected
```

ASP.NET Codebehind(C#)

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getTest()
{
    string theString = "";
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(theString);

    string sortField = "barcode";
    List<Asset> list = new List<Asset>();
    list = AssetManager.getActiveInventoryByOwner("john.doe", "id", "DESC");
    //function takes the following parameters: userid, sort expression, sort direction

     sb2.Append("<table width=100%><tr><thead><th><input type=button value=ID onclick=\"CallSortActiveInventory('" + sortField + "');return false\";></th><th>Serial No.</th><th>Make/Model</th><th>Current User</th><th>Type</th></thead></tr>");
    foreach (Asset item in list)
    {
     sb2.Append("<tr><td style=width:15%;>" + item.Id + "</td><td style=width:20%; text-align:center;>" + item.SerialNumber + "</td><td style=text-align:center;width:15%;>" + item.MakeModel + "</td><td style=width:15%;text-align:center;></td><td style=text-align:center;>" + item.PropertyType + "</td></tr>");
    }
    sb2.Append("</table>");
    theString = sb2.ToString();
    return sb2.ToString();

}
```

JavaScript function

```
function CallSortActiveInventory() {
    PageMethods.getTest(CallSortActiveInventorySuccess, CallPageMethodFailed);
}

function CallSortActiveInventorySuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
    document.getElementById("<%=activeLbl.ClientID%>").innerHTML = result;
}

function CallPageMethodFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
    alert("An error occurred")
}
```

Comment: this line `theString = sb2.ToString();` is pointless... remove all `theString` lines...

Comment: what is the error that you get ?

Comment: I only know there is an error because of the CallPagemethodFailed function which simply raises an alert.  I'm new to JavaScript so I'm not sure how to get the actual error.